# Android How to get the size of application area

Tags: android

[image: Nexus6]

For the above emulator, in my `onCreate` method, how to get the size(height and width) of area of the white space? (not including the `Project1 Screen2`' space)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the view and call this method in on create method

```
 view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
     //now we can retrieve the width and height 
    int width = view.getWidth(); 
    int height = view.getHeight(); 
    //... //do whatever you want with them //... //this is an important step not to keep receiving callbacks: //we should remove this listener //I use the function to remove it based on the api level!
     if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
     view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
     else
     view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
    } });
```

Comment: I am amazed that it gives me the `width` and `height`. Can you give me some detailed explanation about what did the above codes mean?

Comment: If you try to get width and height on oncreate() it will return 0. This listener is called once the layout is loaded